# Function Chaining in Python, ignore rest of chain if a segment returns False

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, python-class

The title pretty much explains the problem. I don't know if there's a practical solution to this or if I'm being too picky over the behavior of my code.
This article was hinting in the right direction, but I never got any code to work.
https://medium.com/@adamshort/python-gems-5-silent-function-chaining-a6501b3ef07e

Here's an example of the functionality that I want:

```
class Calc:
    def __init__(self, n=0):
        self.n = n

    def add(self, n):
        self.n += n
        return self

    def might_return_false(self):
        return False

    def print(self):
        print(self.n)
        return self


w = Calc()

# The rest of the chain after might_return_false should be ignored
addedTwice = w.add(5).might_return_false().add(5).print()

w.print() # Should print 5

print(addedTwice) # Should print False
```

Comment: After calling `might_return_false()`, you are trying to invoque the `add()` method on a object of the class `bool` (`False`), which obviously raises an `AttributeError`

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to keep it from returning any AttributeError, and just return False and stop the chain. Like I said, this might not be possible

Comment: That medium article is low on details and not highly rated. I don't understand what they are saying. "super powerful (and somewhat ‘magical’)" sounds like voodoo

Comment: The thing described in the article could be handled by returning a `unittest.mock.Mock`.  It doesn't sound like a great strategy TBH; the whole "silent" aspect of it means you're inviting difficult-to-find bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will change the structure of my code and try to deal with the errors in a helpful way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the article meant something more or less like below (but I prefer the other answer using exception, as it's more readable and better testable).
Create a helper class:

```
class Empty:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self
    def __getattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self
    def print(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return False
```

and

```
def might_return_false(self):
    return Empty()
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation from the article. I agree with you that it's probably not the way to go for the structure of my script. I don't know which answer I should mark as correct though :P

Comment: IMHO, this answer shows up a great understanding of how Python works. +1 for cool stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are a great way to interrupt a chained operation:

```
class CalcError(Exception):
    pass


class Calc:
    def __init__(self, n: int = 0):
        self.n = n

    def add(self, n: int) -> 'Calc':
        self.n += n
        return self

    def might_raise(self) -> 'Calc':
        raise CalcError

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.n)


w = Calc()

try:
    w.add(5).might_raise().add(5)
    addedTwice = True
except CalcError:
    addedTwice = False

print(w)           # prints 5
print(addedTwice)  # prints False
```

You could also do chains like:

```
w = Calc()
num_added = 0
try:
    w.add(5)
    num_added += 1
    w.add(5)
    num_added += 1
    w.might_raise()
    w.add(5)
    num_added += 1
    w.add(5)
    num_added += 1
except CalcError:
    print(f"Stopped after {num_added} additions")
```

If you attempt to do this with `return` instead of `raise`, you need to check the status at each step of the chain so that you can switch off to some other branch of code (probably via an `if` block).  Raising an exception has the very useful property of immediately interrupting execution, no matter where you are, and taking you straight to the nearest matching `except`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I want to keep try/except as a last resort if silent chain failing just isn't possible.